# Python 2.7, i want to get values between = and , in a string without using multiple split.

Tags: python

Ex: "name=sam,city=london, age=24,location=abc"
I want to get sam, london, 24 and abc in seperate variables. 
Without using split because it results in many useless variables. 
Will regular expression help?
Note: The last value will not have  , 
In this case no ,  after abc. 
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow.com is not an on-demand free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

What's the useless info obtained with split?

```
In [365]: a = "name=sam,city=london, age=24,location=abc"

In [366]: [x.split('=')[1] for x in a.split(',')]
Out[366]: ['sam', 'london', '24', 'abc']
```

Using regex:

```
In [368]: [x[1] for x in re.findall(r'(\w+=(\w+))', a)]
Out[368]: ['sam', 'london', '24', 'abc']
```

Explanation for regex:

```
(\w+=(\w+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8N62JtTzjt1SAJhI)